# Why is UPNPC working on Ubuntu but failing on Debian?

Tags: upnp

Two old PCs, one with WLAN running Ubuntu 18 LTS (kernel 4.15) and the other with ethernet running LUbuntu 20 LTS (kernel 5.15), and a newer laptop with WLAN running Debian 12 (kernel 6.1) are all connected to the same router (Fritz-Box 7560).

PCs with MiniUPnPc (versions 1.9.20140610-4ubuntu2 and 2.1.20190824-0ubuntu2) do work:

```
upnpc -S  # get firewall status
List of UPNP devices found on the network :
 desc: http://10.8.2.1:49000/igddesc.xml
 st: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1

Found valid IGD : http://10.8.2.1:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1
Local LAN ip address : 10.8.2.34
FirewallEnabled: 1 & Inbound Pinhole Allowed: 0
GetFirewallStatus:
   Firewall Enabled: Yes
   Inbound Pinhole Allowed: No
Bytes:   Sent: 136486119        Recv: 1637071899
Packets: Sent:   417893 Recv:   957174
```

Laptop with MiniUPnPc (version 2.2.4-1+b1) fails:

```
upnpc -S  # get firewall status
List of UPNP devices found on the network :
 desc: http://10.8.2.1:49000/igddesc.xml
 st: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1

Found a (not connected?) IGD : http://10.8.2.1:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1
No valid UPNP Internet Gateway Device found.
(exit status is 1)
```

`wget -qO- http://10.8.2.1:49000/igddesc.xml | md5sum` returns the same on all machines (too large to show here). No firewall on the machines. No switches or repeaters.

And, of course, network (internet) is working: no other visible network problems besides this one.

What could be the cause of the malfunction: Linux kernel, distribution, MiniUPnPc library version (same as for MiniUPnPc), client network hardware or something else? How could I debug that?